# Why that difference in outputs of FunctionInjective?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

Trying a new in 12.2 command `FunctionInjective`, I execute

```
FunctionInjective[{Sin[x]^2, Element[x, Integers]}, x]
```

> `False`

and

```
FunctionInjective[{Cos[x]^2, Element[x, Integers]}, x]
```

> `True`

Both functions are even on the reals, so both outputs should be `False` as the output of

```
DiscretePlot[Cos[x]^2, {x, -8, 8}]
```

[image]

shows,

How to explain this difference?

I try to present `Cos[x]^2` as `Sin[Pi/2 - x]^2` and `(1+Cos[2x])/2`, but
the outputs of

```
FunctionInjective[{Sin[Pi/2 - x]^2, Element[x, Integers]}, x]
```

and

```
FunctionInjective[{(Cos[2*x] + 1)/2, Element[x, Integers]}, x]
```

still are `True`.

Comment: I found "a workaround": `ClearAll["Global*"] ; FunctionInjective[{1 - Sin[x]^2,    Element[x, Integers]}, x]` performs `False`. –

Comment: What about `FunctionInjective[Cos[x]^2, x, Integers]`?

Comment: @ChipHurst: I follow  the documentation to `FunctionInjective` which says "Possible values for dom are Reals and Complexes" in the "Details an Options" section. In your syntax `Integers` is simply ignored by the `FunctionInjective` command : `FunctionInjective[Cos[x]^2, x, Integers]` produces the output over the reals. Don't hesitate to ask for further explanation in need.